# How to display related rows in a datagridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to display related rows in DataGridView #2? The data in the linked table is selected by activating the first row selected by the user in the first table (dataGridView1) The set contains data, but datagridview2 does not display them. I was expecting to get a dataset, but it doesn't show up. I 'm wrong about something . I use NetCore7 WinForms
I also tried to bind using Binding, but the result is the same
Below I present the data model and access to it from the form code
How to properly link dataGridView1,datagridView2 and my data model?

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Adress> Adr { get; set; } 
    public List<Work>? Work { get; set; } = null;
    public List<string> Telephonе { get; set; } 
    public List<string> Email { get; set; }
}
namespace Model
{
    public class Adress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set;}
        public string  Street{ get; set;}
        public string House { get; set;}

    }
}

public static class InitialData
{
    public static List<Person> ListPerson { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    static InitialData()
    {
        ListPerson = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Ivan",
                LastName = "Drago",
                Email = new List<string>() { "ivan@xxx.com" },
                Telephonе = new List<string>() { "+0333" },
                Adr = new List<Adress>()
                {
                    new Adress()
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        City = "NewYork",
                        Street = "Street01",
                        House = "33/3/4",

                    },
                    new Adress()
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        City = "Detroit",
                        Street = "Street02",
                        House = "1/3"
                    }

                }
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Petr",
                LastName = "Habbo",
                Email =  new List<string>(){ "petr@vvv.com" },
                Telephonе = new List<string>() { "+888" },
                Adr = new List<Adress>()
                {
                    new Adress()
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        City = "Chicago",
                        Street = "Street03",
                        House = "43",
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    }
}
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = InitialData.ListPerson;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (g == null) return;
        if (g.SelectedRows.Count == 0 || g.SelectedRows.Count > 1)
            return;
        var row = g.SelectedRows[0];
        var Data2 = InitialData.ListPerson
            .Where(x => x.Id.Equals((int)row.Cells["Id"].Value))
            .Select(x =>new { x.Telephonе,x.Email }).ToList();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = Data2;

    }
}
```

Comment: This example does not make much sense. You are selecting the same person again in grid2. It would make sense to display the addresses of the person, as there is a 1 to n relation between person and address. Aslo EMail and Telephone are both lists which may have different lengths. Therefore, you would need a separate grid for each of them.

Comment: Have you actually debugged this code? Besides what's been pointed out in the previous comment, you have `.MultiSelect = false`, then `if (g.SelectedRows.Count == 0 || g.SelectedRows.Count > 1) return;` (?). Just pick the current row, as in: `x.Id.Equals((int)g["Id", e.RowIndex].Value)` and, if you want the first element of each sub-collection, reaplce with `.Select(x => new { Telephone = x.Telephonе?.FirstOrDefault(), Email = x.Email?.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();`. Otherwise, you have to rebuild the resulting collection to include missing members of the `Telephonе` and/or `Email` collections

Comment: You should have noticed that the first DataGridView cannot add a Column for the members of the `ListPerson` collection that are collections themselves

Comment: Thank you for your comments! But I need to display all the phones of a person, he may have many of them, as well as many email addresses. I want to display them (phone and address fields) in different columns in one DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to the anonymous type `{ x.Telephonе,x.Email }` containing two lists. One such object is displayed in one row, but the fields are lists that cannot be displayed in one cell.

The telephone list and the email lists may have different lengths and would have to be displayed separately in two grids or listboxes.

I made a working example by displaying the addresses of the selected person in the second grid.

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = InitialData.ListPerson;
}

private void DataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var person = (Person)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = person.Adr;

    // Assuming that we also have 2 ListBoxes
    listBox1.DataSource = person.Telephonе;
    listBox2.DataSource = person.Email;
}
```

Note that a `List<string>` does not display well in a `DataGridView` as a column is created for each property the bound object, which in case of a string is the `Length` property.

---

If you want to display the phone and email in the same gridview, create a class like

```cs
public class Contact
{
    public string Telephone { get;set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

and in the `Person` class add a property

```cs
public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

This is required, because you cannot display two different lists in the same grid.

Then you can bind with

```cs
dataGridView2.DataSource = person.Contacts;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I need to display all the phones of a person, and he may have several of them, as well as many email addresses. Need to bind DataGridView. I want to display them (phone and address fields) in different DataGridView columns

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, everything worked out! I made a Contact class and put the entities of phone numbers and email in different grids.